# Complex django form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to take input as a list.
This is my forms. py

```
from django import forms
from .models import answer


class SchoolInput(forms.Form):
    school_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'input'
            }
        ))
    num_of_days = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=7, required=True)
    level_of_grades = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, required=True)
    num_of_subjects = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'second_input'
        }
    ))
    name_of_subjects = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'third_input'
        }
    ))
    num_of_lectures = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'second_input'
        }
    ))
    division_check = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Do you have multiple divisions for your grades?',
        choices=answer,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
            'class': 'radiobuttons',
            'style': 'display: block'
        })
    )
```

`num_of_subjects` field and `num_of_lectures` field are the fields where I wanna take input as a list and the number of iterations depend upon the value that'll be provided in `level_of_grades` field. 
Tried list comprehensive in those field but didn't think it was a good idea.
Though these are not forms made in html, is it a good idea to use django forms for this task or make html form?
For better understanding these should be values I would want

```
school_name = 'something'
level_of_grades = 5
num_of_days = 5
num_of_subjects = ['4','3','5','6','9']
num_of_lectures = ['6','7','9','4','3']
name_of_subjects = this will be list with number of lists inside which I'll create once ill understand the logic behind creating a list
division_check = "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides writing your own template to render form or custom form field widget, to create html list input you can use:

- Built-in [SimpleArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#simplearrayfield) which is normal TextInput but splits input by delimiter.
- custom django form fields / widgets, i.e. [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) and  use some fancy select like [Select2TagWidget](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.Select2TagWidget) (looks like [this](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes))

For custom form validation and cross-field validation you can extend [Form `clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method to check that length of list fields is equal to other field value.